# Как написать этот блок в одну строку?

Tags: php, sql

```
$deal = dealRequest($_GET['dealId']);
$connect = mysqli_connect(BAZA_SERVER, BAZA_USER, BAZA_PASSWORD, BAZA_MYSQL);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['name']);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['date']);
$insured = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['insured']);
$obligor = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['obligor']);
$countryObligor = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['countryObligor']);
$amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['amount']);
$currency = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['currency']);
$percent = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['percent']);
$tenor = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['tenor']);
$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['type']);
$responseDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['responseDate']);
$person = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['person']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Не комильфо писать такой код :)
Переходите уже на PDO и подготовленные запросы.

Одна строчка (тоже не комильфо):

```
$_POST = array_map($_POST, function($p) use ($connect) { return mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $p); })
```

Answer (score 1):

используйте `mysqli_prepare` - `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` - `mysqli_stmt_execute`
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$deal = dealRequest($_GET['dealId']);
$connect = mysqli_connect(BAZA_SERVER, BAZA_USER, BAZA_PASSWORD, BAZA_MYSQL);
foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
    $res[$k] = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$connect = mysqli_connect(BAZA_SERVER, BAZA_USER, BAZA_PASSWORD, BAZA_MYSQL);
$deal = dealRequest($_GET['dealId']);
$keys = ['name', 'date', 'insured', 'obligor', 'countryObligor', 'amount', 'currency', 'percent', 'tenor', 'type', 'responseDate', 'person'];

$fields = [];

foreach($keys as $key){
    $fields[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST[$key]);
}
// Если хотите, чтобы каждый элемент массива была доступна по названию переменной.
extract($fields);
// Если оставите строку выше, то можно удалить с памяти fields
unset($fields);
```